# Use ActiveSupport's number helper in a Class Method

Tags: ruby, class-method, activesupport

I have an embarrassingly basic question:

I'm working on a plain-old-ruby model that deals with money, and some of the class methods return prices which need to be formatted for display.

In the past I've used `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` to stick the `number_to_currency` method in a model, but that only works for instance methods.

How do you get that method to be accessible from a class method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `extend`:

```
class MyClass
  extend ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Too much coffee, not enough sleep :)

Comment: Now use `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper`